# Isomorphism and birrationality between projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, projective-space, homogeneous-equation

a) Let $ X $ projective variety and $ S (X) $ your homogeneous coordinate ring

Let $ \phi: \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2 $ given by $ \phi([a: b]) = [a^2: ab: b^2] $ be $ C = Im \phi $. How can I show that $ C \simeq \mathbb{P}^1 $ but $ S(C) \not \cong S (\mathbb{P}^1) $, specifically, how can I see that $ S(C) \not \cong S (\mathbb{P}^1) $

I know $ S (\mathbb{P}^1) = K[x,y] $, how do I calculate $ S (C) $?

b) How can I prove that $ Z(xy-zw) \subset \mathbb{P}^3 $ is birational to $ \mathbb{P}^2 $, but not isomorphic.

Comment: When you write $S(\mathbb{P}^1)=K$, what is $K$?

Comment: $K=\overline{K}$ is the base field

Comment: Usually, then $S(\mathbb{P}^1)$ would be $K[x,y]$. Do you have a different definition?

Comment: it's true, thanks @Mohan

Comment: $S(\mathbb{P}^2)=K[u,v,w]$ and $C$ is defined by $v^2-uw=0$. So, $S(C)=K[u,v,w]/(v^2-uw)$. Hope you can finish the rest.